# How to get odd and even position characters from a string?

Tags: javascript, string, character

I'm trying to figure out how to remove every second character (starting from the first one) from a string in Javascript. 
For example, the string "This is a test!" should become "hsi  etTi sats!"
I also want to save every deleted character into another array.

I have tried using replace method and splice method, but wasn't able to get them to work properly. Mostly because replace only replaces the first character.

```
function encrypt(text, n) {
  if (text === "NULL") return n;
  if (n <= 0) return text;
  var encArr = [];
  var newString = text.split("");
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i += 2) {
    encArr[j++] = text[i];
    newString.splice(i, 1); // this line doesn't work properly
  }
}
```

Comment: What is n parameter in this function?

Comment: If you loop it backwards it will work: `for (var i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 2)`. Indices will be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would probably be easier to use a regular expression and `.replace`: capture two characters in separate capturing groups, add the first character to a string, and replace with the second character. Then, you'll have first half of the output you need in one string, and the second in another: just concatenate them together and return:

```js
function encrypt(text) {
  let removedText = '';
  const replacedText1 = text.replace(/(.)(.)?/g, (_, firstChar, secondChar) => {
    // in case the match was at the end of the string,
    // and the string has an odd number of characters:
    if (!secondChar) secondChar = '';
    // remove the firstChar from the string, while adding it to removedText:
    removedText += firstChar;
    return secondChar;
  });
  return replacedText1 + removedText;
}
console.log(encrypt('This is a test!'));
```

Comment: "!" is missing. In general it won't work for strings with odd length.

Comment: Thanks, forgot the punctuation, make the second capture group optional

Answer (score 6):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the characters of the string and group them to separate arrays using the `%` operator. Use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the 2D array returned to separate variables

```js
let str = "This is a test!";

const [even, odd] = [...str].reduce((r,char,i) => (r[i%2].push(char), r), [[],[]])

console.log(odd.join(''))
console.log(even.join(''))
```

Using a `for` loop:

```js
let str = "This is a test!",
    odd = [],
    even = [];

for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  i % 2 === 0
    ? even.push(str[i]) 
    : odd.push(str[i])
}

console.log(odd.join(''))
console.log(even.join(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function encrypt(text) {
  text = text.split("");
  var removed = []
  var encrypted = text.filter((letter, index) => {
    if(index % 2 == 0){
      removed.push(letter)
      return false;
    }
    return true
  }).join("")
  return {
      full: encrypted + removed.join(""),
      encrypted: encrypted,
      removed: removed
  }
}

console.log(encrypt("This is a test!"))
```

Splice does not work, because if you remove an element from an array in `for loop` indexes most probably will be wrong when removing another element.

Comment: Yup, I know that. That's why I'm trying to find a better solution, because I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What about using filter method? This way it is easy to save removed elements into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple with `.reduce()` to create the two arrays you seem to want.

```js
function encrypt(text) {
  return text.split("")
             .reduce(({odd, even}, c, i) => 
                i % 2 ? {odd: [...odd, c], even} : {odd, even: [...even, c]}
             , {odd: [], even: []})
}

console.log(encrypt("This is a test!"));
```

They can be converted to strings by using `.join("")` if you desire.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track. What you missed is replace is using either a string or RegExp.

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match. If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.

Source: [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

> If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression), only the first instance of the value will be replaced. To replace all occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier

Source: [JavaScript String replace() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

So my suggestion would be to continue still with replace and pass the right RegExp to the function, I guess you can figure out from this example - this removes every second occurrence for char 't':

```js
let count = 0;
let testString = 'test test test test';

console.log('original', testString);

// global modifier in RegExp
let result = testString.replace(/t/g, function (match) {
  count++;
  return (count % 2 === 0) ? '' : match;
});

console.log('removed', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```js
var text = "This is a test!"
var result = ""
var rest = ""
for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        if( (i%2) != 0 ){
          result += text[i]
 } else{
   rest += text[i]
        }
}
console.log(result+rest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with split, filter and join:

```
const remaining = myString.split('').filter((char, i) => i % 2 !== 0).join('');
const deleted = myString.split('').filter((char, i) => i % 2 === 0).join('');
```

Comment: Excellent. I'm using this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array and splice and push each second item to the end of the array.

```js
function encrypt(string) {
    var array = [...string],
        i = 0,
        l = array.length >> 1;
    
    while (i <= l) array.push(array.splice(i++, 1)[0]);
    
    return array.join('');
}

console.log(encrypt("This is a test!"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much you care about performance, but using regex is not very efficient. 
Simple test for quite a long string shows that using filter function is on average about 3 times faster, which can make quite a difference when performed on very long strings or on many, many shorts ones.

```js
function test(func, n){
 var text = "";
 for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i){
  text += "a";
    } 
 var start = new Date().getTime();
 func(text);
 var end = new Date().getTime();
  var time =  (end-start) / 1000.0;
 console.log(func.name, " took ", time, " seconds")
  return time;
}

function encryptREGEX(text) {
  let removedText = '';
  const replacedText1 = text.replace(/(.)(.)?/g, (_, firstChar, secondChar) => {
    // in case the match was at the end of the string,
    // and the string has an odd number of characters:
    if (!secondChar) secondChar = '';
    // remove the firstChar from the string, while adding it to removedText:
    removedText += firstChar;
    return secondChar;
  });
  return replacedText1 + removedText;
}

function encrypt(text) {
  text = text.split("");
  var removed = "";
  var encrypted = text.filter((letter, index) => {
    if(index % 2 == 0){
      removed += letter;
      return false;
    }
    return true
  }).join("")
  return encrypted + removed
}

var timeREGEX = test(encryptREGEX, 10000000);
var timeFilter = test(encrypt, 10000000);

console.log("Using filter is faster ", timeREGEX/timeFilter, " times")
```

[image: filter vs regex - performance test result]

**Using actually an array for storing removed letters and then joining them is much more efficient, than using a string and concatenating letters to it.**
I changed an array to string in filter solution to make it the same like in regex solution, so they are more comparable.